# Pull request analysis not working in Sonar Qube for bit bucket server

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, bitbucket-server

I have SonarQube for Bamboo plugged in and working fine with MSBuild. I also have SonarQube or bit bucket server, which, as far as I can tell, is configured correctly, but pull request analysis is not working. I have a repository in bit bucket configured to allow Sonar Qube analysis and have min. severity set to INFO. But when I click the pull request, a box on the right says:

"Sonar data unavailable. Was not able to fetch data for Sonar project "[project name]:[branch name]". Either the build is not finished yet, your pull request has not been analyzed or a non-existing Sonar project is referenced. You can configure the referenced Sonar project in the repository settings."

The referenced project is configured right in the repo settings, and I have branch analysis for this project working just fine on sonar qube server from the bamboo plugin. The pull request analysis just won't jive while everything else is working. Anyone seen this issue? Any ideas as to why?

Bit bucket server v4.13.0

Sonar for bit bucket server 1.13.1-bbs4

Answer (score 2):

Could you please create a bug report at https://support.mibexsoftware.com ? We can then analyze the issue in detail. It would also help if you could send us the debug logs of the plug-in. I can give you more detailed instructions after we have your bug report.

Thanks,

Michael from Mibex Software

Comment: Bug report sent.